# If the polynomial $P(x)$ is divisible by $x^2-4$ then what is the root of $P(x)$?

Tags: polynomials

I am given 5 choices, only one is correct:

1. $2$ and $-2$ are certainly roots of $P(x)$
2. $2$ is not a root of $P(x)$
3. $-2$ is not a root of $P(x)$
4. $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are certainly roots of $P(x)$
5. $P(x)$ doesn't have real roots

The explanation given is the following:

> By definition the quotient and the rest of polynomial division the question means that $P(x)= (x^2-4)Q(x)$ where $Q(x)$ and the quotient in the division and the remainder is null. Since $2$ and $-2$ cancel the polynomial $(x^2-4)$ and therefore the second member of the previous identity, they must cancel also the first one, which means $2$ and $-2$ are certainly roots of $P(x)$. For this reason the correct answer is 1.

My problem is that I don't understand the explanation. Maybe I am forgetting some properties of the polynomials?

Comment: $P(x)$ is divisible by $x^{2} - 4$ means that there exists some polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $P(x) = (x^{2} - 4)\cdot Q(x)$. Then if we take $x = 2$, we have that $P(2) = (2^{2} - 4)\cdot Q(2) = 0\cdot Q(2) = 0$, thus $2$ is a root of $P(x)$. The same with $x = -2$

Comment: "My problem is that I don't understand the explanation." : Your question is too vague.  Go through the explanation **sentence by sentence**.  Which sentence is the first sentence that you have trouble with?

Comment: Please provide more contexts. If you literally do not understand anything in the explanation, that is a red flag and you would definitely want to go back to the relevant topics and study them. If you believe you studied them but are having trouble linking the learned materials to this explanation, please explain what you learned and which part you are struggling with. At its current form, your answer is too vague.

Comment: Good point everybody. I suppose that I don't understand why is $P(x)= (x^2-4)Q(x)$ . It's probably so obvious, but I am not seeing where this was pulled from.

Comment: You are given that the **polynomial** $P(x)$ **is divisible** by $(x^2 - 4)$.  **By definition**, this means that there exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $P(x) = (x^2 - 4) \times Q(x).$  Similary, if you are given that $P$ is a positive integer divisible by $7$, by definition, that means that there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $P = 7 \times k$.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I think what I was missing was the definition of the quotient in a polyonomy. I am gonna delete the question.